Why Import Error occurs when run the built file using PIL with nuitka when I use conda to create the environment?
I am building a small program to convert pdfs to image files.
So I decided to use the 'pdf2image' package and compile it with 'nuitka' to build it into an exe file.
The compilation was successful and the exe file was also built.
However, I got an Import Error in the Import statement of the source file. (caused Import _imaging on the PIL.Image module)
Here is the error log:
$> # run the programm.
$> .\p2i.dist\p2i.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\gitjob\p2i\P2I~1.DIS\p2i.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\gitjob\p2i\P2I~1.DIS\pdf2image\__init__.py", line 5, in <module pdf2image>
  File "C:\gitjob\p2i\P2I~1.DIS\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 15, in <module pdf2image.pdf2image>
  File "C:\gitjob\p2i\P2I~1.DIS\PIL\Image.py", line 97, in <module PIL.Image>
ImportError

After several tests, we found that the following source also reproduces the problem.
minimu 'p2i.py'
from PIL import Image

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Test")

Commands for building the environment (probably due to this):
# Anaconda Environment Path
$env_path = "(arbitrary env path)"
# Create an Anaconda Environment
conda -p $env_path python=3.10
conda install pillow
conda install pdf2image
conda install -c conda-forge nuitka

I research on the web for this problem (PIL._imaging problem)...
2 or 3 days gone, there is no solution.
I changed my mind: "is the environment broken?" I hypothesized.
And tested same thing on the new environment with this commands:
# Anaconda Environment Path
$env_path = "(arbitrary env path)"
# Create an Anaconda Environment
conda -p $env_path python=3.10
conda activate $env_path
# DO NOT use conda to install packages! use pip this time.
pip install pillow
pip install pdf2image
pip install nuitka

Surprisingly, it worked fine without any options, so easily that trying various options for nuitka seemed futile. I was convinced that the environment was broken...but my experience this time seems to indicate that conda was the cause??
Nuitka command
nuitka --standalone p2i.py

